# Official Help and Support on customising CKAN

Tags: ckan

Please, anyone knows how or where can I get quick support for issues I'm having with CKAN? I work for Argentinian Government and I'm in charge of launching a Open Data Portal for all the country Justice system. I have CKAN running and mostly all information uploaded but for some Datasets and Resources I'm having weird and strange issues that I couldn't track on any site after extensive google searches. Any information of where I can have fast answers and support I will be very grateful. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the best place for support with software is the software's website. Did you try visiting [CKAN's site](http://ckan.org/)?
At first glance, there's a link in the top navigation called "[Support](http://ckan.org/contact/)", so that's where you want to start.
If you are looking for third party vendors to pay to get you up and running, you should clarify that in your question.